# Transaction Rollback to specific set of operations while testing

Tags: c#, rollback

I want to Rollback all transactions while testing my solution from Start-To-Tear without affecting it to real time working on same server. I'm not sure, should i do this cloning of database each time i run my testCases or what. If any advice or solution highly appreciated.

Comment: I hope you don't mean you're wanting to do these tests on the production database.

Comment: yes i'm working on some kind of that

Comment: You should never test against the production database. Spin up a new instance of the DBMS and run your tests against that.

Comment: I don't want to create a new instance of DBMS because of its growing size >32GB.